# What is the correct scaling for PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with a single target

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

With the following setup:

- Apache HttpClient 4.5 PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
- Async(!) Requests from a Website-Controller to a specific backend URL (actually from a service called by the controller)
- Low to medium traffic (like 100 requests per minute max)

what are reasonable settings for `maxTotal` and `defaultMaxPerRoute`?

Comment: assuming that your CS configuration is 1 client and 1 server domain, IMO you should play with a little , invoke various tests at observe the loads and the completion times.